# When I update the database with a new row from the browser, why isn't the SQL Server database table updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm building a blog web application using ASP.NET MVC and Linq-to-SQL database connection.

When I update the database with a new row from the browser (view), the SQL Server database table doesn't get updated.

My controller has two methods as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Administrator> AdministratorList = new List<Administrator>();

    var query = from administrator in context.Administrators
                select administrator;

    var admins = query.ToList();

    foreach (var adminData in admins)
    {
       AdministratorList.Add(new Administrator()
        {
           Id = adminData.Id,
           PublicId = adminData.PublicId,
           Name = adminData.Name,
           Email= adminData.Email,
           MobilePhoneNumber = adminData.MobilePhoneNumber,
           Created = adminData.Created, 
           LastModifiedDate = adminData.LastModifiedDate,
           Code = adminData.Code, 
           CodeExpired = adminData.CodeExpired,
           Role = adminData.Role,
           Active = adminData.Active,
          // Password = adminData.Password
       });
    }

    return View(AdministratorList);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Administrator model = new Administrator();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Administrator model)
{
    try
    {
        Administrator administrator = new Administrator()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Email = model.Email,              
            MobilePhoneNumber = model.MobilePhoneNumber,
            Created = model.Created,
            LastModifiedDate = model.LastModifiedDate,
            Code = model.Code,
            CodeExpired = model.CodeExpired,
            Role = model.Role,
            Active = model.Active,
            //Password = model.Password
        };

        context.Administrators.InsertOnSubmit(administrator);
        context.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `Save()` or its equivilant on the context after adding?

Comment: Are you looking in the correct database? What does the connection string look like? People often connect to a user-instance database file that gets rewritten every time they build the application. Does the connection string conttain an `AttachDbFilename` keyword?

Comment: If you *do* use such a database, don't. The feature is deprecated for quite a few versions now. Hosters hate it because it forces them to install multiple instances of SQL Server Express

Comment: Which version of Entity  Framework are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   the connection string is like that 

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-blog.Web-20170911113114.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-blog.Web-20170911113114;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="BlogConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ENTE1-1DB01\SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=Blog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=glas#3tape"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota im using Linq to sql instead of entity framework

Comment: @DiskJunky yes , i used context.SubmitChanges(); to save changes

Comment: @Fatima that *is* a user-instance database. The data *is* saved but the database *file* gets overwritten each time you restart debugging. Just don't use `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\aspnet-blog.Web-2‌​0170911113114.mdf`. Create a normal database. Open the server in SSMS or Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer and create a new database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How to do that ?? im using Linq to sql database connection and then this code is auto generated in web.config file

Comment: @Fatima it's how *not* to do that. You had to actually specify `AttachDbFilename`, it doesn't get added by itself. Check the duplicate that shows how to connect to a normal database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this code is auto generated in web.config file after creating linq to sql class